# What are the differences between XDefaultScreen and XDefaultScreenOfDisplay?

Tags: xlib

What are the differences between `XDefaultScreen` and `XDefaultScreenOfDisplay`? I can see they respectively return an integer and a struct pointer, but:

- What are those return values used for?
- When would you choose one over the other?
- Why are there 2 functions anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `XDefaultScreen` (usually called by the macro `DefaultScreen`) returns the screen number which is used in most xlib functions where you want to specify a screen e.g. `DefaultGC`.
- `XDefaultScreenOfDisplay` (usually called by the macro `DefaultScreenOfDisplay`) returns a Screen pointer and is generally used when you want to find out information about a screen e.g. `WidthOfScreen`.

Comment: Does the screen structure change as the screen changes, or is it a state?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the ID is also used then, and not always the structure?

Comment: Is there a way to convent one to the other?

Comment: Found it: `Screen *ScreenOfDisplay(Display *display, int screen_number);`.